# How to check if all booleans in a 2D array is true in processing?

Tags: processing

`boolean[][] sth = new boolean[25][25];`

I'm trying to check if all values in the 2D array are true.

Answer (score 1):

In general when working with a 2D array you need two nested for-loops to iterate over all values. As you can see in the [official documentation](https://processing.org/tutorials/2darray/), you could do something like this:

```
boolean allValuesInArrayAreTrue = true;
for(int i = 0; i < sth.length; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < sth[i].length; k++) {
        // if one value is false, set the helper boolean to false
        if(!sth[i][k]) {
            allValuesInArrayAreTrue = false;
        }
    }
}
// now allValuesInArrayAreTrue is true, if all values in the 2D are true
// or false if a single value (or multiple ones) are false
```